# Using a for loop to print a pattern in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to print out this pattern using a for loop in Java but I am kind of stuck.

```
zzzzz   
azzzz  
aazzz  
aaazz  
aaaaz  
aaaaa
```

I can print:

```
 a  
 aa  
 aaa  
 aaaa  
 aaaaa
```

using:

```
String i = " ";   
int a = 0;  
for (i="a";i.length()<=5;i=i+"a")  
    System.out.println(i);
```

and

```
 zzzzz  
 zzzz  
 zzz  
 zz  
 z
```

using:

```
String i = " ";   
for (i="zzzzz";i.length()>0;i=i.substring(0,i.length()-1))  
    System.out.println(i);
```

But I can't figure out how to combine them. I was thinking about replacing the substring of `i` and increasing the value of the end index by one everytime but not sure of to code it. I started with something like this:

```
String i = " ";  
String b = " ";  
for (i="zzzzz";i="aaaaa";i=i.replace(i.substring(0,))  
    System.out.println(i);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pseudocode :

```
for(i <- 0 to 5) {
  print( i times "a" followed by (5 - i) times "z")
  print a new line
}
```

Now implement this in Java.

Comment: G - Like the way you gave him direction without solving the problem

Answer (score 6):

You can increment or decrement more than one variable with the loop

```
for (int a = 0, z = 5; a <= 5 ; a++, z-- )
{
  System.out.println(a+" "+z);
}
```

would output

```
0 5
1 4
2 3
3 2
4 1
5 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In java:

```
public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++) { //This works out the number of lines
            String line = "";
                for(int a=0;a<i;a++) {
                    line+="a";
                }

                for(int z=0;z<(5-i);z++) {
                    line+="z";
                }

                System.out.println(line);       
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For large `i`, this is going to be far more inefficient, though since you spend much less time blocking for I/O, it might turn out to be a very large `i` indeed :)

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi - that is highly unlikely for this particular piece of code.

Comment: Both good points. I did think that it would be easier to understand for the poster as written though.

Comment: @JonH: True enough. Just thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

```
Z = 5
A = 0

while ( Z >= 0 )
{
  for ( i = 0; i < A; i++ ) print 'A';
  for ( i = 0; i < Z; i++ ) print 'Z';
  print newline;
  ++A;
  --Z;
}
```

is one way.

Answer (score 1):

```
String AA = "aaaaa";
String ZZ = "zzzzz";

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(AA.substring(i) + ZZ.substring(5 - i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one additional variable to keep position of a/z border. Increase value of that variable in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
public class pattern2
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int i,j,k,num=0;
        for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=num;j++)
            System.out.print("a");
            for(k=6;k>i;k--)
                System.out.print("z");
            System.out.println();
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very bad formatting. What is the `perfect answer!!!!` doing there?

Comment: Pay attention to your indent next time. Keep in mind that your solution must be clear for the OP